# Find the dimension of the row space of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

this was an exam question and I want to see if I argued it correctly.

$A$ is a $5\times 3$ matrix with nullspace
$$N(A) = \operatorname{span}\{ [2, 1, 0], [1, 3, 0], [1, 1, 0] \},$$
and I have to find the dimension of the row space.

Using rank nullity theorem, I argued that the nullity of $A = 3$ based on $N(A)$, and $q$ being no. of columns, which is $3$, I reached $\operatorname{rank}(A) = 0$.

My understanding is that the transpose $\operatorname{rank}(A^T)$ gives the same value, but for the dimension of row space, which makes sense.

So my eventual answer was $0$.

Is this correct? Thank you!

Comment: Also, would the nullity of A transpose be 5?

Comment: Note that $2 \cdot (2,1,0) + (1,3,0) = 5 \cdot (1, 1 ,0)$. So the last vector $(1,1,0)$ is already in the span of the first two vectors.

Answer (score 1):

$N(A)$ has dimension $2$, so $\mathrm{rank}(A)$ has dimension $3-2=1$, so $\mathrm{rank}(A^T)=1$, i.e. the dimension of row space of $A$ is $1$.

Comment: lol thank you, darn it!

Answer (score 1):

Sadly it's not quite correct. Just because the number of vectors in the system of generators is $3$ it doesn't mean that the *dimension* of the null space is $3$ as well.

In fact, those three vectors can only generate at max the subspace $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \{0\}$ because all have $0$ in its third component. Therefore $\dim N(A) \leq 2$. As two of them are pairwise linearly independent we also have $\dim N(A) \geq 2$.

Therefore we get $\text{rank} (A) = 3 -2 =1$.
The rank of the transpose is the same as the rank of the matrix, because dimension of column and dimension of row space are equal, thus $\text{rank} (A^T) = 1$ as well.

Edit: You could calculate $\dim N(A)=2$ with other techniques as well:

We can see that the dimension is $<3$ because we have a representation of $0$ with non-zero coefficients:
$$
2*(2,1,0) + (1,3,0) - 5*(1,1,0) = 0
$$
But we can generate the space $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \{0\}$ because we can create the generators of this space:
\begin{align}
(1,0,0) &= (2,1,0) - (1,1,0) \\
(0,1,0) &= \frac{1}{2} (1,3,0) - \frac 12 (1,1,0)
\end{align}

Therefore the dimension is at least $2$ and at most $2 \Rightarrow$ it is $2$.

Comment: Ugh, I was afraid so... I knew I felt I was missing something. thank you!

Comment: Happy that I could help you :)

Comment: wow, thank you for the thorough additional explanation!

Comment: yes, very helpful, but darn, this will definitely adversely affect my grade LOL

Comment: Does that clarify your question?

Comment: Oh, I thought you have to do the exam in the future. But that's bad news if you already wrote it :/

Comment: haha yes! I'm happy to learn from my mistakes though so, I'll take the grade (whatever is given) and use this opportunity to study more. :).